# Searching an arraylist of anonymous objects in Java for a specfic variable in those objects

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, switch-statement

I have an assignment that creates an array list that holds contact info objects.  Then I have to ask which field to search from and the information to search.  I am having a hard time figuring the search part out.  I am trying to get into each object and specify which variable to search and find a match.  Here is the sample output I have to create.  My teacher wants to use this code structure for the main and DuEdAddressBook.

This is the area I am having hard time figuring it out.  I want to learn but when you get stuck and all the examples in the book and online do not have this type of scenario it becomes frustrating.  Thanks for any input.

search method: 
Receive ArrayList as argument 
Output Search Menu (see example at bottom) 
Utilize a switch and search ArrayList for field specified. 
Return index number if entry found or -1 if not found

Please Enter First Name: Nick 
Please Enter Last Name: Dewey 
Please Enter Street Address: 3232 Longridge Rd. 
Please Enter City, State: Del City, OK 
Please Enter Zip Code: 73115

Please Enter Field to Search: 1 
Please enter value to search for: Nick 
First Name: Nick 
Last Name: Dewey 
Street Address: 3232 Longridge Rd. 
City, State: Del City, OK 
Zip Code: 73115

Here is my code so far.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class DurrieEdwardChapter10 
 {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
   Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
   String a,b,c,d,e;
   ArrayList<DuEdAddressBook> aBook = new ArrayList<DuEdAddressBook>();

   for (int count = 0; count < 1; count++) 
   {
     DuEdAddressBook entry = new DuEdAddressBook();
     System.out.print("Please Enter First Name: ");
     a = stdIn.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Please Enter Last Name: ");
     b = stdIn.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Please Enter Street Address:");
     c = stdIn.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Please Enter City, State:");
     d = stdIn.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Please Enter Zip Code:");
     e = stdIn.nextLine();
     entry.addEntry(a,b,c,d,e);
     aBook.add(count,entry);
   }
   int foundIndex = DuEdAddressBook.search(aBook); 
   System.out.println(); 
   if (foundIndex > -1)
   {
     aBook.get(foundIndex).display();
   }
   else
   {
     System.out.println("No Entry Found");
   }
 } 
}

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class DuEdAddressBook 
 {
   String first;   
   String last;   
   String street;  
   String state;  
   String zip;

 public DuEdAddressBook()
 {
 }
 public DuEdAddressBook(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e)
 {
   first = a;
   last = b;
   street = c;
   state = d;
   zip = e;
 }    
 public void addEntry(String a,String b,String c,String d, String e)
 {
   first = a;
   last = b;
   street = c;
   state = d;
   zip = e;
 }
 public static int search(ArrayList<DuEdAddressBook> a)
 {
   Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);   
   String searchNum;
   String searchValue;  
   System.out.print("Please Enter Field to Search:");
   searchNum = stdIn.nextLine();
   System.out.print("Please Enter Value to Search For:");
   searchValue = stdIn.nextLine();
   int n = 0; // index of search result
   return n;
 }
 public void display()
 {
   System.out.println("First Name:" + first);
   System.out.println("Last Name:" + last);
   System.out.println("Street Address:" + street);
   System.out.println("City,State:" + state);
   System.out.println("Zip Code:" + zip);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way IMHO is to find the objects via reflection.
Iterate over the List of objects and analyze its field values.
something like:

```
Field[] fields = DuEdAddressBook.class.getFields(); //or getDeclaredFields()
for (Field f : fields)
{
   String fieldName = f.getName();
   Object fieldValue = f.getValue(theDuEdObjectToAnalyze);
   //here you can compare the fieldvalue with the value the user entered
}
```